# Still problems with R CMD check: undocumented S4 classes

Tags: class, documentation, r-s4

I read the long list of questions posted in stackoverlow and other websites about problems with R CMD check and missing documentation. However, I still did not find the correct information to make Roxygen2 to generate the correct .RD file to solve the WARNING in R CMD check.
The WARNING is generated when documenting an S4 class.

I generated a package "TMP" just composed by a S4 class XPSCoreLine

> > > > This is my Roxygen header and the R code:

```
    #' @title class XPSCoreLine
    #' @description definition of the coreLine class for the XPS Core-Line spectra
    #'
    #' @slot RegionToFit the portion of the spectrum to fit
    #' @slot Baseline the Baseline applied to subtract background
    #' @slot Components the fitting components
    #' @slot Fit the best fit
    #' @slot Boundaries the values of the RegionToFit edges
    #' @slot RSF the relative seisitivity factor associated to the element spectrum
    #' @slot Shift the energy correction shift if charging present
    #' @slot units the adopted units: kinetic/binding energy, counts/counts_per_second
    #' @slot Flags logical 
    #' @slot Info information regarding the spectrum acquisition
    #' @slot Symbol symbol of the element associated to the spectrum
    #'
    #' @aliases XPSCoreLine
    #' @keywords XPSCoreLine
    #' @name XPSCoreLine
    #' @rdname XPSCoreLine
    #' @docType class          
    #'
    #' @examples
    #' \dontrun{
    #' test <- new("XPSCoreLine", Info="test", units=c("Binding [eV]", "Counts"))
    #' }
    #' @exportClass XPSCoreLine
    #'

    setClass("XPSCoreLine",
         representation(
                     RegionToFit="list",
                     Baseline="list",
                     Components="list",
                     Fit="list",
                     Boundaries="list",
                     RSF="numeric",
                     Shift="numeric",
                     units="character",
                     Flags="logical",
                     Info="character",
                     Symbol="character"
                     ),
         prototype(
                     RegionToFit=list(),
                     Baseline=list(),
                     Components=list(),
                     Fit=list(),
                     RSF=0,
                     Shift=0,
                     Boundaries=list(),
                     units=c("Binding Energy [eV]","Intensity [cps]"),
                     Flags=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
                     Info="",
                     Symbol=""
                   ),
         contains = "list"  
    )
```

> > > > This generates the following .../man/XPSCoreLine.RD:

```
    % Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
    % Please edit documentation in R/XPSClass.r
    \docType{class}
    \name{XPSCoreLine}
    \alias{XPSCoreLine}
    \title{class XPSCoreLine}
    \description{
    definition of the coreLine class for the XPS Core-Line spectra
    }
    \section{Slots}{

    \describe{
    \item{\code{RegionToFit}}{the portion of the spectrum to fit}

    \item{\code{Baseline}}{the Baseline applied to subtract background}

    \item{\code{Components}}{the fitting components}

    \item{\code{Fit}}{the best fit}

    \item{\code{Boundaries}}{the values of the RegionToFit edges}

    \item{\code{RSF}}{the relative seisitivity factor associated to the element spectrum}

    \item{\code{Shift}}{the energy correction shift if charging present}

    \item{\code{units}}{the adopted units: kinetic/binding energy, counts/counts_per_second}

    \item{\code{Flags}}{logical}

    \item{\code{Info}}{information regarding the spectrum acquisition}

    \item{\code{Symbol}}{symbol of the element associated to the spectrum}
    }}

    \examples{
    \dontrun{
    test <- new("XPSCoreLine", Info="test", units=c("Binding [eV]", "Counts"))
    }
    }
    \keyword{XPSCoreLine}
```

> > > The NAMESPACE contains:

```
    # Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

    exportClasses(XPSCoreLine)
```

> > > > In RStudio the command check_man applied to the package "TMP" just composed by the S4class XPSCoreLine defined above:

```
> check_man("~/R/tmp/")
ℹ Updating TMP documentation
ℹ Loading TMP
ℹ Checking documentation...
✔ No issues detected
```

> > > > However running devtools::check using the command check("~/R/tmp/", document=TRUE)
> > > > I'm unable to get rid of the WARNING

```
checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
  Undocumented S4 classes:
    ‘XPSCoreLine’
  Undocumented S4 methods:
    generic 'hasBoundaries' and siglist 'XPSCoreLine'
  All user-level objects in a package (including S4 classes and methods)
  should have documentation entries.
  See chapter ‘Writing R documentation files’ in the ‘Writing R
  Extensions’ manual.
```

Is there anybody which can suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance
G. Speranza

Answer (score 1):

Following a private mail exchange with Hadley Wickman, the roxygen maintainer, he kindly answered my request suggesting to remove

```
#' @aliases XPSCoreLine
#' @keywords XPSCoreLine
#' @name XPSCoreLine
#' @rdname XPSCoreLine
#' @docType class
```

and replace

```
#' @exportClass XPSCoreLine
```

with

```
#' @export
```

"*Otherwise you've effectively disabled all the S4 stuff that roxygen2 does for you*."

This makes R CMD check to recognize the S4 class 'XPSCoreLine'. I then got a second error from R CMD check:

```
❯ checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING
  S4 class codoc mismatches from documentation object 'XPSCoreLine-class':
  Slots for class 'XPSCoreLine'
    Code: .Data Baseline Boundaries Components Fit Flags Info RSF
          RegionToFit Shift Symbol units
    Docs: Baseline Boundaries Components Fit Flags Info RSF RegionToFit
          Shift Symbol units
```

The slot .Data is implicitly introduced in the S4 class. It is not included in the *representation* and in the *prototype*. I included it in the roxygen header then the correct code for the 'XPSCoreLine' class is:

```
#' @title class XPSCoreLine
#' @description definition of the coreLine class for the XPS Core-Line spectra
#'
#' @slot .Data contains the X, Y spectral data
#' @slot RegionToFit the portion of the spectrum to fit
#' @slot Baseline the Baseline applied to subtract background
#' @slot Components the fitting components
#' @slot Fit the best fit
#' @slot Boundaries the values of the RegionToFit edges
#' @slot RSF the relative seisitivity factor associated to the element spectrum
#' @slot Shift the energy correction shift if charging present
#' @slot units the adopted units: kinetic/binding energy, counts/counts_per_second
#' @slot Flags logical 
#' @slot Info information regarding the spectrum acquisition
#' @slot Symbol symbol of the element associated to the spectrum      
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' test <- new("XPSCoreLine", Info="test", units=c("Binding [eV]", "Counts"))
#' }
#' @export
#'

setClass("XPSCoreLine",
     representation(
                 RegionToFit="list",
                 Baseline="list",
                 Components="list",
                 Fit="list",
                 Boundaries="list",
                 RSF="numeric",
                 Shift="numeric",
                 units="character",
                 Flags="logical",
                 Info="character",
                 Symbol="character"
                 ),
     prototype(
                 RegionToFit=list(),
                 Baseline=list(),
                 Components=list(),
                 Fit=list(),
                 RSF=0,
                 Shift=0,
                 Boundaries=list(),
                 units=c("Binding Energy [eV]","Intensity [cps]"),
                 Flags=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
                 Info="",
                 Symbol=""
               ),
     contains = "list"  
)
```

This removes the last R CMD check warning...